# Guardar valor em um input após inseri-los automaticamente usando Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um select box que define a quantidade de items vão ser exibidos pro utilizador preencher.

http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/dsqBf/55/

Contudo, quando ele deixa de preencher um dos inputs, exibe o erro: "undefined"
Se ele preencher os 5 cmapos, funcionam bem, o problema é quando o utilizador escolhe menos campo.

Como faço para poder recolher os value dos inputs e não exibir esse erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de usar várias variáveis para preencher o resultado, você pode preencher somente uma contendo o texto, e verificar se a entrada é valida.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/dsqBf/59/

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, realmente faz muito mais sentido. Mas eu não tinha nivel tecnico sufience para fazer. Contudo. Existe um erro no seu codigo que corrigi. [  if (i !== qtd - 1) { ] ao ter o "-1", ele não inseria o ultimo valor do input no input das idades totais, ao remove-lo, ja funciona bem.

Comment: Legal @ThallysonDias. Compartilha comigo a nova atualização do Fiddle que atualizo na resposta :)

Comment: aqui esta a versão alterada: http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/dsqBf/59/ na linha 19

Comment: Atualizei, obrigado.